# telnet using node js

Tags: node.js, telnet

1.I have tried using node js to connect telnet. I am trying to control the Epson projector using node js and telnet from my computer.

2.I am running the js code in cmd by:   "node filelocation\test.js"

The code i used:

```
const telnet = require('telnet-client');
const server = new telnet();

// display server response
server.on("data", function(data){
    console.log(''+data);
});

// login when connected
server.on("connect", function(){
    server.write("%1POWR 1\r\n");
});

// connect to server
server.connect({
    host: "192.168.2.170",
    port: 4352
});
```

I am running the js code in cmd by:   "node filelocation\test.js"

The error i get is :

```
TypeError: server.write is not a function
    at Telnet.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TEST\telnet2.js:11:12)
    at Telnet.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\node_modules\telnet-client\lib\index.js:70:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1132:10)
```

Comment: why dont you use the net module instead of telnet-client. I found it much easier to use. I'm not sure about the cannot connect error , though. Make sure you're pointing at the correct IP and port. –https://stackoverflow.com/a/61649900/13126651 this will help you

Comment: i need to send the command "%1POWR 1\r\n" to the ip: 192.168.2.170 and port: 4352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code and it worked for me. Thanks all for the support.

```
 var net = require('net');
    
    var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(4352, 'x.x.x.x', function() {
        console.log('Connected');
        client.write('%1POWR 0\r\n');
    });
    
    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Received: ' + data);
        client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
    });
    
    client.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telnet-client) package and there are no `write()` function available to use. Instead use `exec()`. Also change `on('connect')` like below to catch the errors.

```
server.on("connect", function(err, param){
    server.exec("%1POWR 1\r\n");
});
```

Comment: Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot connect
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\node_modules\telnet-client\lib\index.js:87:25)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:482:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)

Unhandled rejection Error: response not received
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\USER\node_modules\telnet-client\lib\index.js:171:20)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)